# why use of hibernatetemplates is eliminated from spring 3.1 on wards?

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-session

we are starting a new project and in a confusion whether we can use hibernatetemplates or not. But in many of forums found, use of hibernatetemplates is eliminated from spring 3.1+ on wards.  Can any one please provide why hibernatetemplate was eliminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HibernateTemplate` unnecessarily ties your code to Spring classes. However according to document, since Hibernate 3.0.1 you don't need it any more - you can write a code against a plain Hibernate API while using Spring-managed transactions. All you need is to configure Spring transaction support, inject `SessionFactory` and call `getCurrentSession()` on it when you need to work with session.

`Transaction` does all what `HibernateTemplate` was doing and we do not need to depend upon `Spring Class`, that is why it is eliminated from Spring 3.1.